# Get the artwork for an mp3 file

Tags: iphone, mp3, artwork

Hi guys does anyone how you can access the artwork image for an mp3. I download the mp3 from a server and save it in documents, and when i play it from file I want to display the image for the mp3?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the mp3 file downloaded has an image embedded?  More info please

Answer (score 2):

The album art is usually embedded in the ID3 tag. The [id3lib library](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/) can be used to read it.

**EDIT**: There is also the [id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) command-line utility. I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably going to be in the [ID3 tag](http://www.id3.org/Developer_Information). 2.4 and 2.3 ("APIC") are the most common, but 2.2 ("PIC") is still floating around. There are various C libraries which may help.

There's MPMediaItemArtwork, but I think that only works for files in the iTunes/iPod/whatever library.